# How can I enable Wide Char support on g++ over Cygwin?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, cygwin, widechar

guys 'n gals!
I've been trying to build a .cpp I got over the internet for a camera driver. As it is an alpha version, the developer made the stupid decision not to make the compiled program available; instead he simply published the source with the following instruction:

Compile it with: g++ a.cpp -lopencv_core249 -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_imgproc249

I've never ran g++ before because I don't know C++. Yet I did not give up.
A Cygwin install and many downloaded header files later, I'm stuck with the following error:

error Attempted to include wctype.h when uClibc built without wide char support.

Astonishingly, I can't find anywhere online a way to get past this. Could one of you help this damsel in distress? ;)

Comment: Are you crosscompiling ? Seems like your compiler is trying to use a version of uClibc without wide char support.

Comment: I am not. The driver was made for use in Windows (it even calls windows.h)

Comment: If the program is for windows you can not use the cygwin g++ but you should install the `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` package and use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` cross compiler  (mingw64-i686-gcc-g++ for 32 bit)

Comment: @matzeri should I do that in Linux or Windows?